# Database Archiving using Bash Scripting

Tags: mysql, database, bash

I have a MySQL 5.5 transactional database called **vitalstatistix** I wish to archive monthly. The database is made up of one huge table called **asterisk_event** and smaller lookup tables.

The asterisk_event table has a column called **datetime**.

1.I want to extract the year_month part of that column:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM datetime) AS DATEPART  
FROM asterisk_event 
WHERE `datetime` <=  NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH


+----------+
| DATEPART |
+----------+
|   201307 |
|   201308 |
|   201309 |
|   201310 |
|   201311 |
|   201312 |
|   201401 |
|   201402 |
|   201403 |
|   201404 |
|   201405 |
|   201406 |
|   201407 |
|   201408 |
+----------+
20 rows in set (1.31 sec)
```

2. And, for each DATEPART returned above, create a database called **vitalstatistix_'datepart'** e.g vitalstatistix_201307

Each of the created archive databases will contain a month's worth of data.

I need to create a bash script and/or a SQL (MySQL) stored procedure or statements to complement it.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
#!/bin/bash
MUSER="root"
MPASS="password"
MHOST="localhost"
MYSQL="$(which mysql)"
MYSQLDUMP="$(which mysqldump)"


DB="vitalstatistix"
for db in ${DB}
do

# Step 2: Identify the months that need archiving
 echo "$MYSQL -u$MUSER  $db -Bse 'SELECTING .... FROM asterisk_event'"
DATEPARTS="$($MYSQL -u$MUSER -p$MPASS $db -Bse 'SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM datetime) AS DATEPART  FROM asterisk_event WHERE `datetime` <=  NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH')"
echo "[START ARCHIVING]"
echo "Database: "$db
echo ${DATEPARTS}


# Step 3: Create archive databases

   for DATEPART in ${DATEPARTS}
    do
     echo $DATEPART
    #ENTER LINES OF CODE HERE
    done
 echo "[END ARCHIVING]"
done
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: I need to create a bash script and/or a SQL (MySQL) stored procedure or statements to complement it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that...

```
MYSQL="mysql -uuser -ppassword database -BNe"

$MYSQL "SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM datetime) AS DATEPART
     FROM asterisk_event WHERE `datetime` <=  NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH"
   | while read date; do
        $MYSQL "CREATE TABLE vitalstatistix_$date SELECT * FROM asterisk_event 
                  WHERE datetime LIKE '$date%'"
   done
```

One easier thing would be to use a mysql `trigger` when inserting, to insert the data in a second table and each start of the month, renaming this table to `vitalstatistix_<date>` and starting a fresh one.